# Error which accessing appfabric cache from WCF

Tags: wcf, appfabric

I have a WCF service, which is using a dll (Class library) to access Appfabric cache.

When I use this dll to access cache from a console app, it works fine.

However, when I access it through WCF using the client, it gives error "ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified Cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account on the cluster and that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. Retry later.)"

I think this is because, the WCF service tries to access using some other account and not my windows account to access appfabric(which happens in the case of console application).

Any ideas.. how to go about fixing it??

Or is it that my approach is wrong??

Thanks in Advance.

Edit: My WCFService is on local machine and appfabric is on another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried many options out of which two worked..

1. I created same user on app fabric machine in which my IIS was running (ASPNET in case of IIS5). Kept the passwords same.and added it as the the account in appfabric.
2. Changed the security settings in the config file of the WCF to:

   ```xml
   <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None" />
   ```

Rightnow, I am using option 2.